# Load Spark RDD to Neo4j in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, neo4j, cypher, pyspark

I am working on a project where I am using **Spark** for Data processing. My data is now processed and I need to load the data into **Neo4j**. After loading into Neo4j, I will be using that to showcase the results.

I wanted all the implementation to de done in **Python** Programming. But I could't find any library or example on net. Can you please help with links or the libraries or any example.

My RDD is a PairedRDD. And in every tuple, I have to create a relationship.
**PairedRDD**

```
Key   Value
Jack  [a,b,c]
```

For simplicity purpose, I transformed the RDD to

```
 Key  value
 Jack  a
 Jack  b
 Jack  c
```

Then I have to create relationships between

```
 Jack->a    
 Jack->b
 Jack->c
```

Based on William Answer, I am able to load a list directly. But this data is throwing the cypher error.

I tried like this:

```
 def writeBatch(b):
    print("writing batch of " + str(len(b)))
    session = driver.session()
    session.run('UNWIND {batch} AS elt MERGE (n:user1 {user: elt[0]})', {'batch': b})
    session.close()

def write2neo(v):
    batch_d.append(v)
    for hobby in v[1]:
        batch_d.append([v[0],hobby])

    global processed
    processed += 1
    if len(batch) >= 500 or processed >= max:
        writeBatch(batch)
        batch[:] = []


max = userhobbies.count()
userhobbies.foreach(write2neo)
```

b is the list of lists. Unwinded elt is a list of two elements elt[0],elt[1] as key and values.

**Error**

```
ValueError: Structure signature must be a single byte value
```

Thanks Advance.

Comment: hello ,how you transformed your 
      Key   Value
     Jack  [a,b,c]   
to
     Key  value
 Jack  a
 Jack  b
 Jack  c

Comment: @A.HADDAD Using UNWIND operator

Comment: Please ? unwind is a spark or a python operator , i want to use in my java-pair-rdd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a `foreach` on your RDD, example :

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", auth=basic_auth("",""), encrypted=False)
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()
dt = sc.parallelize(range(1, 5))

def write2neo(v):
    session = driver.session()
    session.run("CREATE (n:Node {value: {v} })", {'v': v})
    session.close()


dt.foreach(write2neo)
```

I would however improve the function to batch the writes, but this simple snippet is working for basic implementation

**UPDATE WITH EXAMPLE OF BATCHING WRITES**

```
sc = SparkContext()
batch = []
max = None
processed = 0

def writeBatch(b):
    print("writing batch of " + str(len(b)))
    session = driver.session()
    session.run('UNWIND {batch} AS elt CREATE (n:Node {v: elt})', {'batch': b})
    session.close()

def write2neo(v):
    batch.append(v)
    global processed
    processed += 1
    if len(batch) >= 500 or processed >= max:
        writeBatch(batch)
        batch[:] = []

dt = sc.parallelize(range(1, 2136))
max = dt.count()
dt.foreach(write2neo)
```

-
Which results with

```
16/09/15 12:25:47 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
writing batch of 500
writing batch of 500
writing batch of 500
writing batch of 500
writing batch of 135
16/09/15 12:25:47 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 279, boot = -103, init = 245, finish = 137
16/09/15 12:25:47 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1). 1301 bytes result sent to driver
16/09/15 12:25:47 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) in 294 ms on localhost (1/1)
16/09/15 12:25:47 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
16/09/15 12:25:47 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (foreach at /Users/ikwattro/dev/graphaware/untitled/writeback.py:36) finished in 0.295 s
16/09/15 12:25:47 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: foreach at /Users/ikwattro/dev/graphaware/untitled/writeback.py:36, took 0.308263 s
```

Comment: Answers looks pretty Good but how about the huge datasets. How to implement the same for huge datasets in batch processing as you said.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example for batching writes

Comment: I am facing an error when unwinding the key value pairs. 
    session.run('UNWIND {batch} AS elt MERGE (n:user1 {user: elt[0]})', {'batch': b}).  Where elt[0] is key and I have a list of values in value. How can we unwind all this into cypher.

Comment: Chris, I achieved this. Thanks for the help. Cheers.